# How to create a custom button with an action in md-data-table

Tags: angular-material

I am wondering how add an new custom button in the table.  I have try to add some default or build-in buttons by the way below:

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon>delete</md-icon> // default in setting
    </md-button>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon>add</md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon>update</md-icon>
    </md-button> 
     <md-button class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon>whatever</md-icon>  // fail to show in the page
    </md-button>
```

I can get add,update and delete icons by calling names between `<md-icon>` tags. However, I am not sure How to button works and where each icon stores in the file. How this program loads or refers to the icons by specific names. Where to insert a block of code to interact with such as delete, update or add functionalities? Can anyone explain to me?

Github reference:https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well what do you need, but I think that you want to trigger an action when clicking a button in a cell of the data table, 
if this is what you wants, you just need to add a on click action :
`<md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-onclick="action()"></md-button >`
here is an example :

http://codepen.io/Has1/pen/jVEgMx?editors=1010